# What permission controls access to "webform_html_editor" input type?

Tags: webforms

I'm a Drupal site owner, and my admins cannot access any webform_html_editor elements.

The administrators have full access to all wysiwyg inputs, but there is no permission obvious to me that controls access to this field.

What permission grants access to edit the webform wysiwyg?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

Webform wysiwyg uses the "Webform (Default)" input type, which doesn't show up on the "input filter" admin listing, but does show up in the permissions table.

Granting this permission unlocks the webform_html_editor wysiwyg.